# Finding all one-parameter subgroups of a matrix Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Trying to put some theory into practice before an exam without any lectured examples, so forgive me if this is simple... I have the subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ given by
\begin{equation}
G=\bigg{\{}\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}:a,b\in\mathbb{R},a\not=0\bigg{\}}
\end{equation}
which I would firstly like to show is a Lie group under matrix multiplication, a secondly find all its one-parameter subgroups.

It's obvious to me this is not a closed subgroup (so we can't apply Cartan's theorem and conclude $G$ is an embedded Lie subgroup and hence a Lie group), and unlike the subgroups $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ etc. I can't write $G$ as the inverse image of a regular value of a smooth map and apply the IFT. How else could I show $G$ is a smooth manifold?

I'm also trying to find all one-parameter subgroups of $G$, i.e. all Lie group homomorphisms $\sigma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow G$. I've tried writing such a map explicitly in terms of functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ and arrive at the conditions $a(t+s)=a(t)a(s)$ and $b(t+s)=a(t)(1+b(s))$, but this doesn't seem very neat. I also have the fact that $G$ is isomorphic as a group to invertible linear transformations $T$ on $\mathbb{R}$ of the form $T(x)=ax+b$ but I don't know if this helps.

Could someone please help me with this example, since all I have at the moment is theory and am struggling to put it into practice. Thanks

Comment: Why is $G$ not a closed subgroup of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$? (Presumably you mean to restrict to $n = 2$ given your definition of $G$.) Also, you can write $G$ as the inverse image of a point under the projection map that sends a matrix onto its bottom row.

Comment: To get the 1-parameter subgroups just consider $\exp(tA)$ where $A$ runs through the Lie algebra elements of $G$ (what are they?).

Comment: @Travis I was imaging matrices with $a=1/n$ and $b=0$. Then these would lie in $G$ but their limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ wouldn't. I'll try the projection suggestion when I'm back at my desk!

Comment: @jl2 Your argument shows that $G$ is not a closed subset of the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices. But the limiting matrix of your sequence is not in $GL_2(\Bbb R)$. On the other hand, $G$ *is* a closed subset of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$, and the inverse image argument shows this.

Comment: @Travis Ah yes, of course. So if $\tau:GL_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{1\times2}$ maps $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix}c&d\end{pmatrix}$, then $G=\tau^{-1}(\begin{pmatrix}0&1\end{pmatrix})$ which is closed since $\tau$ is continuous. Then either we can see $G$ as a closed subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and hence a Lie group by Cartan's theorem, or alternatively show $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is a regular value of $\tau$ and apply the IFT.

Comment: And the latter is easy because $\tau$ being linear means we can identify it with it's differential, and surjectivity of the differential then follows easily from this.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I will try work out the Lie algebra now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, $G$ *is* a closed subset of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$.

The one-parameter subgroups are exactly the maps $\Bbb R \to G$ defined by
$$\phi_X : t \mapsto \exp(t X),$$
for $X \in \mathfrak g \cong T_I G$.

In our case, it's straightforward to check that under this identification (and the identification of $T_I G$ as a subspace of $T_I GL_2(\Bbb R) = T_I M(2, \Bbb R) \cong M(2, \Bbb R)$) the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of $G$
$$\mathfrak g = \left\{\pmatrix{a&b\\0&0} : a, b \in \Bbb R \right\},$$
so it remains just to produce an explicit formula for
$$\exp\left[ t \pmatrix{a&b\\0&0\\}\right] = \exp\pmatrix{at&bt\\0&0} .$$
One way to handle this is to write the matrix on the r.h.s. as $A + B$, where
$$A := \pmatrix{at&0\\0&0}, \qquad B := \pmatrix{0&bt\\0&0} ,$$
which enables simplification of the expression for the exponential when using the formula $\exp X = 1 + X + \frac{1}{2} X^2 + \frac{1}{6} X^3 + \cdots$ that holds in the matrix group setting.

Comment: I am new to Lie groups/algebras. Could you elaborate how you found $\mathfrak g$? Is there some procedure?

Comment: Yes. As usual we identify $\mathfrak g$ with the tangent space $T_I G$ at the identity, and any tangent vector can be represented as the velocity vector $\gamma'(0)$ of some curve $\gamma = \pmatrix{\alpha(t) &\beta(t) \\ \cdot & 1}: J \to G$ be a smooth path satisfying $\gamma(0) = I$. Computing gives $$\left.\frac{d}{dt} \pmatrix{\alpha(t) &\beta(t) \\ \cdot & 1} \right\vert_0 = \pmatrix{\alpha'(0) &\beta'(0) \\ \cdot & \cdot} .$$

Comment: Ah, thanks so much for your quick reply!